# Double clicking MacroButton field not recognized by VBA after dismissing modal Windows Form

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, vsto, word-field

I am developing a word add-in using VSTO. There are several MacroButton fields on the Word document surface involved. In order to address the fields' double-click events, I am using a VBA macro in a template (MyTestProject.dotm).

This is the structure of one of the feilds:
[image]

When field codes are hidden, it displays as `TESTTAG: Test1`.

When double-clicking on the `TESTTAG: Test1`, below script within the `MyTestProject.dotm` excutes:

```
Public Sub TPS_TestTag()
    Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("MyVSTO")
    Set automationObject = addIn.Object
    automationObject.HandleClickEvents
End Sub
```

I have the following method in the `AddInUtilities.cs` of my VSTO project:

```
public void HandleClickEvents()
{
    using (MyProject.Application app = new MyProject.Application())
    {
        app.ExecuteMacroClickEvents();  
    }
}
```

Within the `app.ExecuteMacroClickEvents()` method, I the `form.ShowDialog()` method to display a modal Windows Form.

On my first double-click on the `TESTTAG: Test1`, my form is appearing. Then the `TESTTAG: Test1` appears selected:

[image]

If I close the form and immediately double-click on the `TESTTAG: Test1` tag again, without clicking anywhere else, `TPS_TestTag()` within the `MyTestProject.dotm` is not executed. If I again double-click on the tag, the VBA executes and shows the dialog. If I close the dialog again and continue with the double click, dialog will not show, in next try - dialog shows.This same behavior continues.

On the other hand, when using the `form.Show()` method to show the Windows Form the issue doesn't occur.

You can use the below method in the `AddInUtilities.cs` in the VSTO project to replicate this issue.

```
public void HandleClickEvents()
{
    Form objForm = new Form(); 
    objForm.Width = 300;
    objForm.Height = 300;
    //objForm.Show();      /* This doesn't give the issue */
    objForm.ShowDialog();  /* This gives the issue */
}
```

Now my question is:

I really need to use the `objForm.ShowDialog()` method to show the dialog and at the same time I need to pop-up the dialog on every double-click on the `TESTTAG: Test1` MacroButton field without any failures.

**Update**

Testing on the issue again, identified that after a double click the document is in a mode like 'not active'. When I single click on somewhere of the document, I am able to double click again. I tried below codes within AddInUtilities class and also within the `TPS_TestTag()` VBA method. But non of them worked.

```
object word = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
wordApp = (Word.Application)word;    
wordApp.ActiveDocument.Activate(); //or
wordApp.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.Select();
```

VB code

```
Public Sub TPS_TestTag()
    Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("MyVSTO")
    Set automationObject = addIn.Object
    automationObject.HandleClickEvents
    Word.ActiveDocument.Activate
End Sub
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Not sure this has anything to do with the problem but: 1) WHAT is `Myproject.Application` and why is the code in the VSTO solution creating a new instance each time one of these methods is called? And are these instances being cleaned up anywhere we aren't seeing?

Comment: @CindyMeister I modified `HandleClickEvents`, 'code for replicate' in the question. Even we show the form with `objForm.ShowDialog();`  without creating  `MyProject.Application` instance, the issue recreates. 


I have a class named `Application.cs` within `MyProject`. It is the main class within `MyProject` where many of other objects got created. 
"are these instances being cleaned up anywhere we aren't seeing" : Isn't it automatically clean-up when handled within the 'using' block (using calls Dispose() after the using-block is left) ? Do I need to cleaned them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.

Should call `SetFocus` method for Active Document within `AddInUtilities.cs` class right after the related code execution is finished.

```
public void HandleClickEvents()
{
    using (MyProject.Application app = new MyProject.Application())
    {
        app.ExecuteMacroClickEvents();  
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.SetFocus();
    }
}
```

or modifying the VBA code,

```
Public Sub TPS_TestTag()
    Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("MyVSTO")
    Set automationObject = addIn.Object
    automationObject.HandleClickEvents
    word.Application.ActiveWindow.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Reference : Last comment in [this forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/62d03be0-f4f5-49eb-9da2-63a8bd1b2a3f/how-do-i-make-the-word-window-active?referrer=https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/62d03be0-f4f5-49eb-9da2-63a8bd1b2a3f/how-do-i-make-the-word-window-active?forum=worddev)